# Running Batch Stript in Windows 7 causes process to be launched under wrong cmd process

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-services

Whenever I run a batch file on my comuter (64 bit architecture running 64 bit windows 7), the console window that is opened is running in 32-bit mode, and checking the task manager confirms I am indeed running everything as a 32-bit process.  I want to run the batch file under a 64-bit process, not a 32-bit process.  I have changed the comspec environment variable to point to the proper variable, to no avail.  Does anyone know how to fix this so that when I click on the batch file, it everything is run in 64-bit mode.

I realize I could simply open the 64 bit command window and run my batch file.  However, this is a workaround and doesn't get at the root of the problem, and won't help when I give file to others.

Thanks,
MM

Comment: If your batch file ends in .bat, try changing the extension to .cmd

Comment: Good idea, Gilbert, but it looks like both filetypes run off of the PATHEXT by default (`ftype batfile` = `batfile="%1" %*` and `ftype cmdfile` = `cmdfile="%1" %*`), so they would need to be tweaked to do something different.

Answer (score 1):

Are the file associations for .cmd associated with the 32bit cmd.exe or the 64bit cmd.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the scripts with the full path name to the executable? 
`"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c <batch_name>` should run 64-bit
`"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /c <batch_name>` would run in 32-bit

Otherwise, you could change the associations to run the extension .cmd with 64-bit (`ftype cmdfile=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "%1" %*`) and .bat with 32-bit (`ftype cmdfile=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c "%1" %*`).